# simple_fields_for with check_boxes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

Good night friends!

In a form with many through, I need to display all the objects of a given class (tool), with a checkbox field and text field next to it. My form is as follows:

```
= simple_form_for @service, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
   - @tools.each do |tool|
      = f.simple_fields_for :instrumentalisations, tool do |i|
         = i.input :tool_id, tool.id, as: :check_boxes
         = i.input :amount
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
 Undefined method `tool_id 'for # <Tool: 0x007faef0327c28> 
 Did you mean To_gid
```

Models

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :partitions, class_name: "Partition", foreign_key: "service_id"
   has_many :steps, :through => :partitions
   has_many :instrumentalisations
   has_many :tools, :through => :instrumentalisations

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :instrumentalisations
end

class Tool < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :instrumentalisations
   has_many :services, :through => :instrumentalisations

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
end

class Instrumentalisation < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :service
   belongs_to :tool
end
```

Controller

```
def new
   @service = Service.new
   @service.instrumentalisations.build
end

def edit
   @tools = Tool.all
end

def create
   @service = Service.new(service_params)

   respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
         format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 def service_params
    params.require(:service).permit(:name, :description, :price, :runtime, :status, step_ids: [], instrumentalisations_attributes: [ :id, :service_id, :tool_id, :amount ])
 end
```

Thank you!

Comment: The fact that this field: tool_id being a foreign key interferes with something?

Comment: I noticed that when I change from

`= f.simple_fields_for :instrumentalisations, tool do |i|`
      
to 

`= f.simple_fields_for :instrumentalisations do |i|`

it introduces me to several tool objects, it seems like duplicates

Answer (score 0):

the error is quite simple: **tool** doesn't has a `tool_id` method. BUT, why are you asking this to a tool object instead of a instrumentalisation object?

So, you're trying to create some `instrumentalisations` but you're passing a `tool` as object:

```
f.simple_fields_for :instrumentalisations, **tool** do |i|
```

[`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) requires a `record_name`, whith in this case is `:instrumentalisations` and the 2nd arg is the `record_object`, which *should* be an `instrumentalisations` object and **not** a `tool` object.

So to fix it would have to pass an `instrumentalisation` object. You can accomplish that by:

```
f.simple_fields_for :instrumentalisations, Instrumentalisation.new(tool: tool) do |i|
```

Of course this isn't the best solution since if you edit this object would be building a lot of new `instrumentalisations`.

I'd recommend the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), which makes it easier to handle nested forms!

Comment: Actually, that's not quite what I need. I would like to display all the objects of the tools class, with a checkbox field to mark them and another text field to append the amount of items. In that case the cocoon gem will not solve my problem. [This article here](http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/), presents something as close as I'm looking for, however I need to add one more field and use the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

Comment: the error was that you were passing a tool object into a instrumentalisations loop.

Using the fields_for passing a new Instrumentalisation is just one of the ways you could archive what you're trying to do.